# How to write Federated SPARQL request in Protege

Tags: sparql, ontology, federated

Can somebody help me please with SPARQL Federated, because I can't understand it syntax.

For example I have my own local ontology (museum domen) and there are some data regarding weather I find this https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting.

How can I view information from this ontology (weather and date, for example) and my ontology (excursion and date)?
I tried to create request here https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP4150%20%3Fstatement0.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement0%20%28ps%3AP4150%29%20_%3AanyValueP4150.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20LIMIT%20100%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D but it does not work in Protege.

I tried to create request in Protege:

```
*** PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>
PREFIX foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?date ?excursion
FROM <https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting>
    WHERE <http://www.menthor.net/myontology> foaf: ?excursion .
  SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting/sparql> { 
    ?date foaf:date ?date . ***
```

but it does not work again

What prefixes should I have? Can I get data from this link https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting in Protege?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR10c.png) I can get data from my ontology, but do not understand how to use dbpedia data

Comment: neither is `https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting` the URL of the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint nor is `foaf:date` any property in DBpedia - did you just randomly declare this property? I mean, did you check your link what property is used to declare a date?

Comment: also, your query is neither complete not syntactically correct as shown here ...

Comment: Property dbp:date declare the value, for example, 2005-04-29 (xsd:date)

Comment: that is correct, but `dbp:date` is **not** `foaf:date` as you're using in your query. It also doesn't make sense to use the prefix `foaf:` for two different namespaces in your query, you should use an own prefix for your custom namespace.

Comment: that pattern will also never work: `?date foaf:date ?date ` - or when is the subject and object of a triple a date at the same time.

Comment: also illegal syntax: `WHERE <http://www.menthor.net/myontology> foaf: ?excursion .`

Comment: okey, first of all I write this and it is working
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>

SELECT ?excursion 
WHERE {
 ?excursion rdf:type [ rdfs:subClassOf* :Name_of_the_tourTS] .
       
}

Comment: Then I add dbp service and it still doesn not work and I do not see any errors in Protege:  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>


SELECT ?excursion ?date ?value
WHERE {
?excursion rdf:type [ rdfs:subClassOf* :Name_of_the_tourTS] .

SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting> 
{
?date ?dbp:date .
?value ?xsd:date .   
}                
 }

Comment: as I said before, `SERVICE <dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting> ` is wrong - the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint URL is not the HTML page of a particular DBpedia website. The endpoint URL is `https://dbpedia.org/sparql` - also, the DBpedia entity resource URI for Wether_forecasting is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weather_forecasting`

Comment: Okay, and should I use prefix for dbpedia? Because now I have an error (undefined prefix
)

Comment: yes, you have to add the prefix declaration for the `dbp:` prefix or just use the full URI instead

Comment: I have default Protege prefixes: PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
then I have added prefix for my ontology: PREFIX boldino: <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>
and prefix for dbpedia: PREFIX dbp: <https://dbpedia.org#>
Is it correct? No errors, but still don't work ;C

Comment: PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX boldino: <http://www.menthor.net/myontology#>
PREFIX dbp: <https://dbpedia.org#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?excursion ?date ?value
WHERE {
?excursion rdf:type [ rdfs:subClassOf* boldino:Name_of_the_tourTS] .

SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> 
{
?date dbp:date ?date .
?value xsd:date ?value . 
 
}                
}
LIMIT 5

Comment: no, you're missing fundamental things of RDF and SPARQL. I mean, hover the `dbo:date` link on the website and you'll see the URI. Also `?date dbp:date ?date` does not make sense: 1) why should a date literal be in subject and object position of a triple? And then, what is ` ?value xsd:date ?value . ` ? I don't get what you're trying to do with this

Comment: PREFIX dbp: <https://dbpedia.org/property/date#> create prefix in this way?

Comment: I  thought ?date dbp:date ?date  is like date sub class of dbp:date and variable date should get it

Comment: Do you know where can I find triple that include date in https://dbpedia.org/page/Weather_forecasting?

Comment: no ... you still don't understand the concept of prefixes ... it should be `PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>` and then use `dbp:date` - it shouldn't be so difficult to understand the concept of prefixes, namespaces and URIs.

Comment: - also `?date` is just a literal of datatype `xsd:date`. Something else has a date, in your case the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weather_forecasting` has the date asserted.

Comment: Should I use FROM <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weather_forecasting>  
or  
WHERE { graph <http://dbpedia.org> {?date a <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weather_forecasting>}   ?

Comment: no ... you should read an RDF tutorial first I think. and then come back to SPARQL - the `SERVICE` has to be the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint, and this contains all the RDF triples, also the date of the resource Weather_forcasting. I don't get why you think now  `?date a <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Weather_forecasting>` is the way to go? Are you randomly creating those things? Why should a date be of type `Weather_forecasting`? the keyword `a` is an alias for `rdf:type` which in fact connects individuals to its type resp. class.

Comment: Is it correct? SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql>

Comment: do I need to have # at the end? PREFIX dbp: <https://dbpedia.org#> or not?

Comment: I tnink the problem is here
 {
?date dbp:date ?date .
?value xsd:date ?value .

Comment: Schould I use it in this way? {?sub ?obc . } or {?sub prefix:relationship between classes obj .} or somth else?

Comment: I tried many examples drom Internet in my Protege sparql (for example, PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX sehr: <http://hcls.deri.ie/l2s/sehr/1.0/>
SELECT ?diabetes ?bmi ?cases ?hypertension
WHERE { ?dataset a qb:Dataset.
?observation qb:DataSet ?dataset;
a qb:Observation; sehr:Daibetes ?diabetes ;
sehr:BMI_Abnormal ?bmi ;
sehr:Hypertension ?hypertension ; sehr:Cases ?cases . }
) but id does not work
maybe I have a problem with Protege?